# C++ Destructor Usage when deleting an object containing a dynamic array as a data member

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, memory-leaks

I've written two classes: Student and Course. The Course class has a Student *students as a data member in its body. In my top class StudentReviewSystem, I have a Course *courses as a data member, and I have a deleteCourse(const int courseId) method which deletes the course with "courseId and resizes "courses". Here is my code of deleteCourse method:

```
void StudentReviewSystem::deleteCourse(const int courseId){
int index = 0;
bool found = false;
//temp arr
Course *temp = new Course[courseSize];
for(int i = 0; i < courseSize && !found; i++){
    if(courseId == courses[i].getCourseId()){
        index = i;
        found = true;
    }
}
if(found){


    temp = courses;

    courses = new Course[courseSize-1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= index-1;i++ ){
        courses[i] = temp[i];
    }
    for(int i = index+1; i < courseSize; i++){
        courses[i-1] = temp[i];
    }


    delete[] temp;

    cout << "Course has been deleted!" << endl;
    courseSize--;
}
```

}

When I try to delete temp, I get a "glibc detected" error with a memory map under it and at the then aborted(core dumped) error. But when I comment out the line delete[] temp; , it works. Can you help me, I'm really new to C++.

Thank you...

P.S: When I comment out the ~Course(){ delete[] students;} destructor, it again works. I think I have a really silly problem, thank you again...

Comment: You're leaking memory. `Course *temp = new Course[courseSize];` is *always* abandon and leaked in this code. This isn't Java. And by the looks of it your `Course` class isn't practicing the [`Rule of Three`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)) *at all*.

Comment: Replace all those arrays with `std::vector` or some other standard container, and use smart pointers and standard algorithms - you could reduce that function to about three lines that don't contain raw news or deletes. You're leaking a  `Course[courseSize]` there. I suspect you're double-deleting students if they can belong to several courses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the typical mistake: your class has a dual responsibility.

The solution is simple:

- one class to handle the technical issue of a dynamic (possibly resizable) array
- one class to handle the functional requirements, using the first class to achieve its goal

The first class is already available (`std::vector`), if necessary (aka, your teacher ask it of you) then you can recode a `std::vector`; otherwise use it as is. Read more on [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Since the bug is in Course, using vector<Course> here won't help much. Using vector<Student> in Course too might well be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you are not following the rule of three in your Course class.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for full details.

You should follow the rule of three in every class you write. Because you haven't followed the rule of three then any attempt to copy a Course object (like you are trying to do above) will crash your program.

I would say understanding the rule of three is the first step to becoming a decent C++ programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to delete an array that has not been allocated by new.